# Configuring MessageTransformer for ActiveMQ/Stomp in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a springboot project with ActiveMQ and Stomp.
I want every Message sent or received to run through a MessageTransformer, to do specific serialization/deserialization stuff. 
The Stomp Message exchange with my WebApp works, but the installed MessageTransformer is never called. 
Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong? Thank you much!

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.MessageTransformer;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value("${stomp.port}")   // 61616
    int stompPort;


    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = 
                    new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

        // Install Message Converter ## But does not work ##
        MessageTransformer messageTransformer = new ClientMessageTransformer();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setTransformer(messageTransformer);

        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public BrokerService brokerService() throws Exception {

        BrokerService brokerService = 
                 BrokerFactory.createBroker(String.format(
                   "broker:(stomp://localhost:%d)" +
                   "?persistent=false&useJmx=false&useShutdownHook=true", 
                    stompPort));

        return brokerService;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending and receiving using a STOMP client or is there an actual ActiveMQ client in the mix, it isn't clear from the question what the flow is

Comment: I have a javascript web client, using Stomp JS to send and receive messages to/from the server.

Comment: So why are you configuring an ActiveMQConnectionFactory with a message transformer if you are only using STOMP clients?

Comment: Its because i Have a Custom serializer i want to Use for the Messages from Server to the client.

But i Have seen Spring itself also hast message Transformation concepts. I currently Figure this out. So it would be done on a more higher Level and Not Depending on the actual Provider like activemq.